# Getting linking error while using STL containers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl

I am getting following  linking error, while running my C++ code in VS2008 in which I have used C++ STL :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::_Tree<class 
std::::_Tmap_traits<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,
class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>
,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct
std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::
allocator<char> > const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,
class std::allocator<char> > > >,0> >::iterator parser::parsedDataIterator"
(?parsedDataIterator@parser@@2Viterator@?$_Tree@V?$_Tmap_traits@V?$basic_string@DU?$
char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits
@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char
_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@$0A@@std@@@std@@A)   parser.obj
```

I haven't associated any library with the code, don't know if there is there any need for the same.

Below is the code that is compiling successfully:

```
//Including header file that just contains the class declaration
#include "parser.h"

//Static variable definitions...
int parser::lang = -1;
std::string parser::fullString;
std::map<std::string, std::string> parser::parsedData;
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator parsedDataIterator;
std::stack<char> parser::symbolStack;

//The parsing function used to parse XML content..
bool parser::XMLParser(std::string arg_String)
{   
    //Create empty strings...
    std::string tagText;
    std::string emptyString = "";
    //Maintain count for string length
    int count = 0;

    //Loop over whole string...
    for(unsigned int i=0 ; i<arg_String.length() ; i++)
    {
        //ignore white string when not reading internal tag text content...
        cout<<"Value of i : "<<i<<" ... Value of str.char is :"<<arg_String[i]<<endl;
        if(arg_String[i] == ' ' && count==0)
            continue;

        if(arg_String[i] == '<'){
            symbolStack.push(arg_String[i]);
            tagText.clear();
        }
        else if(arg_String[i] == '>'){
            symbolStack.pop();
            parsedData[tagText] = "";
        }
        else{
            tagText.push_back(arg_String[i]);
            count++;
        }


    }
    if(symbolStack.empty())
    {
        cout<<"XML parsing was successful :"<<endl;
        return true;
    }
}

bool parser::populateAndReturn(std::string arg_String)
{
    bool status = false;
    status = XMLParser(arg_String);
    return status;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string inputString = "<html>";
    if(parser::populateAndReturn(inputString))
    {
        for(parser::parsedDataIterator = parser::parsedData.begin(); parser::parsedDataIterator != parser::parsedData.end(); ++parser::parsedDataIterator)
        cout << "Key: " << (*parser::parsedDataIterator).first << " Value: " << (*parser::parsedDataIterator).second;
    }
    else
        cout<<"\nError encountered while parsing";
    system("pause");
}
```

Code for "parser.h":

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class parser
{
    static std::string fullString;
        //Declaring a map that will associate the tag with the container text.
    static std::stack<char> symbolStack;

public: 
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> parsedData;
    static std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator parsedDataIterator;

    parser(){
    }

    static int lang;

    static enum format{
        XML,
        JSON,
        ZZZ = -1
    };

    static bool populateAndReturn(std::string arg_String);
    static bool XMLParser(std::string arg_String);
};
```

Comment: http://sscce.org please.

Comment: @chris added code for clarity...thanks

Comment: I suspect that you've left out a required header, such as `<string>`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Added code for parser.h and I've already included <string> in parser.h..thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left off the classname from the the parser::parsedDataIterator.

In your definitions of the `static` members, change:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator parsedDataIterator;
```

to:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator parser::parsedDataIterator;
                                           //^^^^^^^^
```